# Angular Unit Testing error with export 'default' (imported as '__NG_CLI_RESOURCE__1') was not found

Tags: angular, unit-testing, error-handling, jasmine

I am getting error when running ng test/npm test, here is the error. I am not sure why this is happening.

[image]

Can I get some help please?
I checked the tsConfig.json and it looks correct to me-

```
"target": "es2017",
    "module": "es2020",
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.